# Why is malloc() allocating 2 more bytes than its supposed to?

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I'm writing a c- compiler. Flex recognizes my string token and sends it to a function to store it in a struct{} containing info about it, but first the string needs to have escape chars removed, which is a ''. Here is my code that does that:

```
char* removeEscapeChars(char* svalue)
{
    char* processedString; //will be the string with escape characters removed
    int svalLen = strlen(svalue);
    printf("svalLen (size of string passed in): %d\n", svalLen);
    printf("svalue (string passed in): %s\n", svalue);
    int foundEscapedChars = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < svalLen;) 
    {
        if (svalue[i] == '\\') {
            //Found escaped character
            if (svalue[i+1] == 'n') {
                //Found newline character
                svalue[i] = int('\n');
            }
            else if (svalue[i+1] == '0') {
                //Found null character
                svalue[i] = int('\0');
            }
            else {
                //Any other character
                svalue[i] = svalue[i+1];
            }
            i++;
            foundEscapedChars++;
            for (int j = i; j < svalLen + 1; j++) {
                svalue[j] = svalue[j+1];
            }
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    int newSize = svalLen - foundEscapedChars;
    processedString = (char*) malloc(newSize * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(processedString, svalue, newSize * sizeof(char));
    printf("newSize: %d\n", newSize);
    printf("processedString: %s\n", processedString);
    printf("processedString Size: %d\n", strlen(processedString));
    
    free(svalue);
    return processedString;
}
```

It works 99% of the time, but when its tested on this specific string (or a similar one with 40 characters) "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN", malloc() appears to be allocating memory for a string 2 bytes too large. The output for this is below. Notice that I used int newSize in my call to malloc(), which it says is of value 40, and then strlen() returns 42. sizeof(char) is == 1 also. The main issue is its inserting garbage characters at the end of the string. What gives?

```
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
svalLen (size of string passed in): 40
svalue (string passed in) "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
newSize: 40
processedString: "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"Z
processedString Size: 42
Line 47 Token: STRINGCONST Value: "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"Z Len: 40 Input: "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

Comment: I can't quite follow all the logic, but I don't think your `memcpy` is copying the terminating null character.  As a result, calling `strlen` on `processedString` is likely to overrun it, as you saw.   (When you fix this, make sure you adjust the `malloc` to allow space for that null character as well.)

Comment: This would be *considerably* more efficient if you scanned for escape characters, kept count of how many you need, allocated, and dumped over with offsets. Right now you painfully shuffle the string back each time you find an escape character. The more escape characters you have the slower it gets.

Comment: I think it just random memory from outside  allocated... Basically you didn't copy \0... That's from where buffer overflow attacks come

Comment: So in short: "Why is malloc() allocating 2 more bytes than its supposed to?"  It's not - *you* are accessing (at least) 2 more bytes than you allocated.

Comment: It's also extremely rude to `free()` an argument you're given. You don't own that. You can't presume that you can even `free()` it. `removeEscapeChars("test")` explodes. Let the caller deal with the cleanup if/when it is necessary. *Do not presume* to know better than the caller.

Comment: @tadman ..unless the function is a destructor:)

Comment: @MartinJames Then it should say it is on the tin, or else... *surprises*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reworking of your code that takes a different, more conventional approach to processing strings. Start first with a function that counts escape characters, as this will be useful in the next step:

```c
int escapeCount(char* str) {
    int c = 0;

    // Can just increment and work through the string using the given pointer
    while (*str) {
        // Backslash something here
        if (*str == '\\') {
            ++str;
            ++c;
        }

        if (*str) {
          // Handle unmatched \ at end of string
          ++str;
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

Now using that information you can allocate the correct buffer size:

```c
char* removeEscapeChars(char* str)
{
    // IMPORTANT: Allocate strlen() + 1 for the NUL byte not counted
    char* result = malloc(strlen(str) - escapeCount(str) + 1);
    char* r = result;

    do {
        if (*str == '\\') {
            ++str;

            switch (*str) {
                case 'n':
                    *r = '\n';
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    *r = '\r';
                    break;
                case 't':
                    *r = '\t';
                    break;
                default:
                    *r = *str;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            *r = *str;
        }

        if (*str) {
          ++str;
        }

        ++r;
    } while(*str);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. I thought it was copying the '\0' at the end, but I wasn't thinking correctly about how strlen() wasn't accounting for it. Also thanks for the more efficient code. As for the free() on the argument, I was calling the function by using strdup(str) for the arg, so it was freeing a copy of the string. I wont need to do this anymore with the way you did it. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth keeping your functions as narrow in scope as possible and avoid unanticipated side-effects. This function purports to "remove escape characters" and either modifies in-place or returns a copy based on the function signature. A comment or documentation would make it even more clear what it does.

Comment: If you want to improve this even more, you could convert that clunky `switch` with a simple look-up table, as in a 127 character long string you can use like `escapeChar[n]` where `n <= 127`.

Answer (score 3):

Code has at least this problem: attempting to print a "string" that is not a *string* as it lacks a terminating *null character* and space to store it.

That leads to *undefined behavior*.  This UB might exhibit itself as printing extra characters.

```
// processedString = (char*) malloc(newSize * sizeof(char));
// memcpy(processedString, svalue, newSize * sizeof(char));
processedString = malloc(newSize + 1);
memcpy(processedString, svalue, newSize);
processedString[new_Size] = 0;
```

---

Likely other issues too.